# Getting 'ResultSet is closed' when running query second time

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to pass a sql query but i am getting "java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" . I have gone through other conversation based on same exception in stackoverflow but still I don't understand the problem.

Here is the code:

```
String query="SELECT candidate,pan from hcl_candidates where    jngstat='Joined'";

statement=conn.createStatement();
resultset=statement.executeQuery(query);

while(resultset.next()){

statement.executeUpdate("insert IGNORE into allinvoice       (candidate,pan,invdate,client) select candidate,pan,CURDATE(),'HCL' from hcl_candidates where jngstat='Joined'");
}
}

//catch block

finally 
{
try
{

if(statement!=null)
{
statement.close();
}
if(conn!=null){
 conn.close();
 }

if(resultset!=null){
resultset.close();
 }
}
 // catch block
 }
```

here is error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
//So on
```

Comment: Your  program is not being blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-executing the `Statement` closes the prior result set.

It's hard to understand what you think you're doing here, executing a statement in a loop that doesn't rely on anything that the loop changes.

NB An `SQLException` can mean a lot of things besides 'unable to connect'.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the loop, now it works.. i was supposed to delete it ,but it must have skipped my mind :)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with executing the `executeUpdate` in a `while` loop on the same Statement object. This violates the expectation of the [Statement class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

PS: You should first close the result set, Statement and then Connection.

Comment: Hi i have added my stack trace...please let me know if u know anything

Comment: `while` loops do not 'violate the `Statement` class'.

Comment: It is not the while loop as such. My intent was to say that executing the `executeUpdate` on the same `Statement` object was causing the issue. Please refer to the Oracle doc of the `Statement`  class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: I agree. It isn't the `while` loop as such. But that's what your answer says. If there's more to it, it should appear in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I included this in the answer now.